# Using custom/existing bluetooth HID with iOS Devices?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, hid, mfi

I am working on building or using an existing bluetooth HID device (something like this http://www.icontrolpad.com) and to get my iOS device to read the data coming from it. So i have some questions regarding this:-

1. Is it possible at all to do this, considering that the Bluetooth stack is not available on non jail broken devices.
2. Do i need to register with apples Mfi program? If i don't need to, what are the alternatives?
3. If i do register with Apple's Mfi program will i get access frameworks that will allow me to read data off the Bluetooth stack.
4. Considering that there will be a custom application sitting on the iOS device that needs to communicate with the HW im building, what are the implications w.r.t the approval of the app from Apple's side?

Thanks in advance, any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Core Bluetooth framework is available for Bluetooth Low Energy devices on iOS 5, no MFi membership is required.

Comment: Thank you! Ive been searching for Bluetooth Smart HID devices (preferably a mouse or a free space motion controller) and havent come across too many that suit what i need. Do you have any information or suggestions for the same? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

With Made for iPhone, you basically get a serial pipe to your device using the ExternalAccesory Framework (in fact, it IS using the  serial port profile plus some authentication). So you while you cannot use an actual HID device, you could send your data over.